# Upgraded RAM not showing up

Tags: upgrade, ram, 20.04

I was given a Lenovo IdeaPad S145 to use for university. However, it only comes with 4GB of ram so I decided to install a further 8GB (DDR4-2666 SODIMM) in order to up the performance. I did check online and the ram seemed to be compatible

I have now installed the ram, but it is not showing up when I look in the terminal as well as when I look in the BIOS. 
[Here is the picture from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkdEC.png).
I have also wiped the drive and completely reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 which did not help either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[Edit] Ended up updating BIOS which didn't help. Then struggled to boot into memtest so I sent the laptop in. Turns out it was just faulty ram

Comment: Do you have to tell your BIOS about the new memory? Can you boot into `memtest`?

Comment: If it also does not appear in the BIOS, how is this related to Ubuntu? This sounds like a hardware compatibility or configuration issue.